# Jetpack compose: Rendering the vector asset based on the boolean value

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've been playing with Jetpack Compose, and trying out few things. One of those is rendering the vector assets (svgs).

I have created a custom checkbox component. Here's the code:

```
@Composable
fun CustomCheckBox(
    checked: Boolean = false,
    onClick: (() -> Unit)?,
    children: (@Composable() () -> Unit)? = null
) {
    val imgRes = if (checked) R.drawable.ic_checkbox_on else R.drawable.ic_checkbox_off
    val vectorAsset = +vectorResource(imgRes)

    Clickable(onClick = onClick) {
        Row(modifier = Height(100.dp) wraps Expanded) {
            Container(
                width = vectorAsset.defaultWidth.value.dp,
                height = vectorAsset.defaultHeight.value.dp
            ) {
                DrawVector(vectorImage = vectorAsset)
            }
            Container(modifier = Spacing(top = 10.dp)) {
                children?.invoke()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's some more code so that we have a full picture:

```
@Composable
fun TermsConditions(state: TermsAndConditionsState) {
    CustomCheckBox(
        onClick = {
            state.accepted = !state.accepted
        },
        checked = state.accepted,
        children = {
            Text(text = "I accept the Terms of Service\" or \"I accept the Privacy Statement\" \"Click here to indicate that you have read and agree to the terms presented in the Terms and Conditions agreement.")
        }
    )
}
```

My model class:

```
@Model
data class TermsAndConditionsState(var accepted: Boolean)
```

I'm having an issue thou: whenever I click on the checkbox component, the state change gets triggered (the `accept` flag is inverted). However, it's not reflected in the UI. Surprisingly, it works with PNGs.

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong? Or is it just a bug in Compose? I know it's in very early dev stage, so the wrong behavior can be expected.

Comment: Although you are using some old version of Compose, the problem is still valid for 0.1.0-dev07. On dev07 the result is bit surprising: Only first change "works", but in reality after first check two resources are drawn on top of each other and the old one is never cleared (you can check that by choosing resources that are completely different in shape, you will see that they overlap). As a (stupid) workaround you can add such if statement: `if (checked) { DrawVector(vectorAsset) } else { DrawVector(vectorAsset) }`, so the entire `DrawVector` changes instead of just it's content. ‍♂️

Comment: You're welcome:) 
I've also submitted it as a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152712588

Comment: As per the comments in the bug report, the problem should be fixed in Dev15.